# How do I mirror an image right to left?

Tags: java, image

I'm having trouble editing this code on having it mirror an image from left to right because when I received the code it mirrored the image on right to left.

```
public void mirrorVerticalRightToLeft() {
    Pixel[][] pixels = this.getPixels2D();
    Pixel leftPixel = null;
    Pixel rightPixel = null;
    int width = pixels[0].length;
    for (int row = 0; row < pixels.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col > width/2 ; col++) {
            leftPixel = pixels[row][col];
            rightPixel = pixels[row][col-1-width];
            rightPixel.setColor(leftPixel.getColor());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.dyclassroom.com/image-processing-project/how-to-create-a-mirror-image-in-java

Comment: Looks like the trouble you're having is that you've made no effort to change the code and are expecting us to do it for you.

Comment: I did edit the code but wasn't getting any luck with doing so, so upon me asking on here I just put the code that was given to me hoping someone could explain what they did and help me understand how I could change it so I could apply what they say on trying to mirror an image from bottom to top. So if you are not willing to help your comment is not needed

Comment: Or maybe your question is not needed...

Comment: *"So if you are not willing to help your comment is not needed"* On that topic.. *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. **Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.** See: How to create a [mcve]."*. To clarify, the 2nd thing I quoted was a close reason that now 3 different people have chosen.  So when @shmosel mentions *"maybe your question is not needed..."* they are closer to the mark.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the inner for loop does not run at all, as the condition is wrong.

It should be "col < width/2", instead of "col > width/2".

At the beginning col = 0, so it's not really larger than width/2, and loop exits immediately, without doing any work.